# Duplicate keys in tcl associative array

Tags: hashmap, tcl, associative-array

I am using associative array/hash map to store some data. I want to keep duplicate entries that have same key  but different values. Currently, the previous key is being overwritten by the last instance.

> key: LVL values: vdd,vddr

> key: LVL values: vddi,vdd

Comment: Have a list as a value under the key `LVL` and append to it if another entry came along

Comment: Are you using a dict or an array?

Comment: Oh, and are you already storing a list of values? The lack of actual code in your question makes it unclear.

Comment: This is how associative arrays work: the keys are unique. You'll need to create a more complex data structure to meet your needs: for example, as suggested, an array of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multimaps are, in general, implemented as ordinary maps to lists of items. (There's a few other ways, algorithmically, but they're rare in practice except in a few degenerate cases.) In Tcl, you do this by appending to the list in the element on creation and using nested loops on read out:

```
# With arrays
foreach {key item} $thingsToPutIn {
    lappend map($key) $item
}

foreach {key items} [array get map] {
    foreach item $items {
        puts "$key => $item"
    }
}
```

```
# With dictionaries
foreach {key item} $thingsToPutIn {
    dict lappend map $key $item
}

dict for {key items} $map {
    foreach item $items {
        puts "$key => $item"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot merge values of the same key. I may have to rename the key to key_duplicate1 to manage this case.

Comment: Well, the underlying mechanism used doesn't permit duplicate keys. It uses exact string equality on keys to decide when two things are the same.